# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import cx_Oracle
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('hap_prod_dev/hap_prod_dev@192.168.31.128/ORCL')#This line of an error
c=conn.cursor()
x=c.execute('select sysdate from dual')
x.fetchone()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

**In python 3.6**

I tried to connect to the database, and I got this error,**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode**

Comment: plz show full backtrace.

Comment: Also, what version of cx_Oracle are you using?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback/error you get when you attempt to connect to the db with cx_Oracle? The error you mention appears to just a general python codec/encoding error and not specifically related to your use of cx_Oracle